# Encoding problem with a geopackage

Tags: geopackage, encoding

I received a geopackage file and one of the attribute contains encoding mistakes for the Swedish letters ö, ä, å. How can I fix this with QGIS or FME ?

[image]

Comment: GeoPackage standard requires UTF-8 and therefore I guess there are no ready made tools. I think I would convert data into some text based format like GML or GeoJSON and use text editor with search/replace for fixing the data. Then conversion back to GeoPackage. How did you manage to create such GeoPackage, is there a reason to make a bug report for some software?

Comment: I received the GeoPackage the way it is and have to work with it... This search/replace solution would be too difficult as I don´t know original names... And also all the 3 possible letters are show with �

Comment: QGIS has a "Set layer encoding" tool in the processing toolbox (it didn't change the layer, only how the layer is read during the current session), Also in QGIS on the layer property (source tab) there are a dropdown to choose encoding (that also only change it in the  current session)

Comment: Can you share the GPKG or is it confidential?

Comment: (It could be "parishes", which is now called "distrikt". You can create an account and download them for free here: https://www.lantmateriet.se/sv/Kartor-och-geografisk-information/geodataprodukter/produktlista/distriktsindelning/#steg=1)

Comment: This is more likely a *display* issue than a data one, but if the data is corrupt, there is no easy solution to repair it.

Comment: FTP folder GSD-Distriktsindelning has only Mapinfo and Shape as download alternatives. Am I following a wrong path?

Comment: No, that is the only alternatives. I meant OP can download shapefiles and convert to gpkg

Comment: @J.R, both your solutions cannot work. GPKG does not support changing the attribute encoding, sadly even for display.

Comment: @aae didn't know that about gpkg.... So I guess the solution is to export to another format fix the encoding issue then save as gpkg again...